# No Provider for NgControl in sub component of Angular app

Tags: angular

I've installed & am able to use the *QuillModule.QuillEditorComponent* perfectly fine in the AppComponent of my Angular app.

But when I try to use it in a different module, I'm getting the below error:

[image: error]

Here is the current structure of my project:

[image: structure]

Here is my *auth.module.ts*:

```
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';

import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  imports: [QuillModule.forRoot(), CommonModule, FormsModule, AuthRoutingModule]
  })
export class AuthModule { }
```

And here is the code in my *dashboard.component.html*:

```
<div id="quill">
  <p>Content *</p>
  <quill-editor [styles]="editorStyle" placeholder="Enter Text" [modules]="config" formControlName="yourCtrlname"
    required>
  </quill-editor>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here? If I use this code in *AppComponent*, there are no issues & the module appears as expected.

The above HTML is also in my AppComponent, & displays the editor like so:

[image: editor]

Comment: formControlName can only be used inside of a FormGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to add the provider as well,

```
providers: QuillModule.forRoot().providers
```

Comment: https://github.com/trotsm/animals-of-ukraine/blob/f63f74a5e7886c2dab729520d27359ae5950b612/src/app/admin/shared/shared.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see `formControlName="someControlName"` you're using reactive forms. Your template for dashboard.component.html is using reactive forms. Since this component is declared in the `AuthModule`, you'll need to also import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the `AuthModule`.

It probably works in your `AppComponent` because you're probably importing the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the `AppModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  imports: [
      QuillModule.forRoot(),
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule, 
      ReactiveFormsModule,   // <---NEW!!! 
      AuthRoutingModule
     ]
  })
export class AuthModule { }
```

Since you're using reactive forms, you will also need to put your component inside a `<form>`

```
<form [formGroup]="myEditorForm" id="quill">
  <p>Content *</p>
  <quill-editor [styles]="editorStyle" placeholder="Enter Text" [modules]="config" formControlName="yourCtrlname">
  </quill-editor>
</form>
```

And lastly, setting up the form in the `dashboard.component.ts`:

```
export class DashboardComponent {
   myEditorForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      yourCtrlName: new FormControl('a default value', Validators.Required)
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code definitely doesn’t work inside app component unless there is a FormGroup wrapping it or you remove the formContorlName directive (otherwise, it's not really working, see below), as formControlName can only be used as a child of a FormGroup inside the same component template.

I guess I'll explain this more since apparently this isn't clear.

formControlName relies on a parent FormGroup to function as it injects and accesses the parent group (or array, as it may be).  Without this parent FormGroup, the formControlName cannot function as it has nothing to draw its control from and no provider for NgControl, which is the error you're seeing.  You MUST wrap it in a FormGroup. Your alternative is to pass in the control directly and use it with the `[formControl]` directive instead.

the reason this "works" in AppComponent is because you're not importing the FormsModule into your AppModule, so angular is ignoring the formControlName directive entirely.  It is not "working" as there is no form control binding taking place, the bug is just less explicit and harder to spot. if you import the FormsModule, you will see the same error.

as you do here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-cxrikb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: What I mean is that the text editor displays as expected in the AppModule, but when used in the Dashboard component, nothing is displaying, & I get the error message

Comment: There’s no way it’s displaying if it has a formControlName directive attached to it without a FormGroup around it. FormContolName 100% always absolutely MUST be a child of a FormGroup

Comment: Sigh, no it isn’t. Why don’t you go ahead and create a blitz where you have a formControlName directive functioning without being a child of a FormGroup. I’ll wait.

Comment: @user9847788 also added an explanation for you of why it appears to be "working" in app component (hint: it's not)